# Residue of $e^{z+\frac1z}$ at $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to compute
$$\text{Res}\: (e^{z+\frac1z}, 0)$$
and can't get a solvable integral using the definition of a residue.
I already know other ways to compute residues of poles of arbitrary order, but nothing for essential singularities- and I believe this is the case here.

Comment: $\exp(x)*\exp(1/x)$ Now use taylor expansion on second exponential.

Comment: @MrYouMath $exp(1/z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!z^k} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^0 \frac{z^k}{k!}$, and thus it I only dealt with that it would have been $Res = a_{-1} = 1$, but I have to deal with the multiplication with the infinite sum of the other part.

Comment: hint for $0 < |z| < \infty$ : $(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!})(\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-m}}{m!}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^n \sum_{m \ge 0,k \ge 0, k-m = n} \frac{1}{m!}\frac{1}{k!}$ (both series converge absolutely so you can change the order of summation)

Answer (score 6):

$f(z)=e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}=[1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+......][1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2.2!}+....]$.

$Res[f(z);z=0]=$coefficient of $1/z$ in $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$\frac{1}{n!.(n+1)!}$

Comment: The sum form of $f(z)$ seems to be missing a factor of $z^n$

Comment: It is the coefficient of $1/z$ only.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I misread as "coefficient of $1/z$ in ... $f(z)=\sum$"

Comment: No problem, it still feels good to scrutinize your old maths writing.